# Strange php error at login page

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am currently working on a log-in page which accesses a mysql database with a user and password table. Whenever I try to run my code I get the following error no matter what I comment:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/scs/licenta/an2/gr927/rpie1814/public_html/testphpathome/login.php on line 15

Here is the main page in HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Gaming site
    </title>

</head>
<body>

<h1>
    Log-In
</h1>

<form action="login.php" method="post">
    Username: <br>
    <input type="text" name="user"> <br>
    Password: <br>
    <input type="text" name="pass"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the php code:

```
    <?php

$user = $_POST["user"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];


global $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "rpie1814", "rpie1814", "rpie1814");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users";
global $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 1)
{
    header("Location: /game.php");
    exit;
}
else
{
    echo "Unknown user";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
exit;

?>
```

Comment: Remove `global` from connection and result

Comment: @replace `$connect` with `$con`

Comment: hey why you have used global word. any specific reason?????

Comment: Thank you for the global comment, Salty. That fixed the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `global` from connection (`$conn`) and result (`$result`):-

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "rpie1814", "rpie1814", "rpie1814");
```

AND

Replace:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
```

To:-

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); // actually your connection variable is $conn not $connect
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
global $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
```

by:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

Comment: I replaced it. Thank you, but the same error persists. Now it says it's on line 13.

Comment: Did you replace `$connect` with `$conn`?